# Patching a string using DLL injection and OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg, c++, memory, dll-injection

I'm a novice when it comes to RE but I'm trying to get into it. I have a background in C/C++ so doing the development side of things should be a breeze (aside from when assembly has to be used, im rusty there). I just need to be pointed in the right direction with RE things and will be able to pick things up from there.

I wrote a simple CLI program (HackMe.exe) to practice RE with, using OllyDbg. It just has a string("change me") which I'm attempting to change (patch?) via a DLL.

Here's the CLI prog source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* change_me = "change me";

    while(true) {
        std::cout << change_me << std::endl;
        Sleep(3000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the DLL source so far which is bare bone

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

VOID attach();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE module, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {

    switch(reason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: {
            CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&attach, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

VOID attach() {
    // patching code will go here
}
```

So far what I've done is

- Attached OllyDbg to running HackMe.exe process
- Searched for all referenced text strings and followed the "change me" string

Following the the string brought me to where the string was found

[image]

So correct me if I'm wrong or not including something but I believe I need to

- Find the base address of the process and the offset to the string address
- Patch the memory at base + offset with a new string thats len is == to the original

**So i guess my questions are**

1. How do I find the base offset of process (I assume I can do in the DLL using something like GetModuleHandle("HackMe.exe"))?
2. Is there a way to see the base offset in OllyDbg (not that useful I suppose since the base will more than likely change every time the exe is ran)?
3. How do I find the +offset of the string from the base?

**Working end result**

```
#include <Windows.h>

VOID attach();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE module, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved) {

    switch(reason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: {
            attach();
            break;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

VOID attach() {

    DWORD old;
    DWORD base   = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD offset = 0x01CC80;

    char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(base + offset);
    const size_t length   = 10;
    char buffer[ length ] = "changed:)";

    VirtualProtect(ptr, length, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old);
    memcpy(ptr, buffer, length);
    VirtualProtect(ptr, length, old, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be creating threads in DllMain it isn't recommended  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283/ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. How do I find the base offset of process (I assume I can do in the DLL using something like GetModuleHandle("HackMe.exe"))?

A process doesn't have a base offset; I believe you mean the base address of the primary module. To get that address, you would use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`.

> 2. Is there a way to see the base offset in OllyDbg (not that useful I suppose since the base will more than likely change every time the exe
>      is ran)?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will show you the base address of each loaded module.

> 3. How do I find the +offset of the string from the base?

There are countless ways to do it, but an easy way is to use a tool like IDA or [BinText](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/bintext.aspx) to find the string's virtual address, and then subtract from that the default base address of HackMe.exe.

Comment: wouldn't the **std::string change_me** be a stack / heap / copy of the original string ? is changing the original string in the exe be enough ? to change the string outputted by cout() ?

Comment: Correct, I did mean base address. Thanks for the answers.